# How to validate image in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying laravel image validation for the following field-

```
<label class="btn btn-success">
    <input name="image" type="file"/>Add Image</label>
    @if ($errors->has('image'))
       <span class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ $errors->first('image') }}
       </span>
    @endif
```

And my validation rule is written like this-

```
$request->validate([
  'image'=> 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:1000',
]);
```

But no matter what whether I give a valid image as input or not my validation rule gives me this error-

**The image must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png, gif.**

You can consider me beginner in laravel and I cant really find out what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using the `image` validation rule ?

Comment: Haven't you forgot to add the enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form?

Comment: can u post the full form?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I actually forgot the enctype in my form. @Ruub special thanks to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this set of rules for your `image` input field:

```
'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif',
```

This will:

- make the field `nullable`, so you can send it as `null`
- `image` to validate the filetype (see [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-image))
- `mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif` that will check for specific file mime type ([doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimes)) (also check [mimetypes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-mimetypes))

You can even [check image idmension](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-dimensions).
Take a look at [available rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules), [custom validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) and the [intervention image](http://image.intervention.io/) package.